# How to consolidate FME readers into one?

Tags: fme-form, personal-geodatabase

I have an FME Workbench file that was built up slowly over time and has ended with many readers and many writers (each to a separate feature class), even though every reader points to the same geodatabase (in this case an Esri Personal Geodatabase).

[image]

Now I am trying to tidy up the file to remove duplication of transformers to make it easier to maintain the file over time (it is use for data translation daily), and I would like to also consolidate all the readers into one.

I found that with the Writers, I could just open each writer's properties and use the drop-down to select a different writer, so just changed them all to point at the same one (this worked perfectly!)

[image: Writer Feature Type Properties]

However, for the readers there is no drop-down, the reader property is read-only here, so I can't easily change which reader needs to be used

[image: Reader Feature Type Properties]

How can I re-point each feature type to use the same reader, like I can easily with the writers?

Comment: Do your writers all have different Table Names?

Comment: @nr_aus My _writers_ are all different feature classes (different names) and are into a different geodatabase

Comment: It looks like an FME limitation, I was able to replicate the issue in 2018.1..... You probably already know this, but I would use the 'Update Reader' function on your first reader, and then expose all tables required from that first reader. which should add them as reader icons onto your workbench canvas, then repoint the connector lines manually.

Comment: Correction - 'Import Feature Types' .....not Update Reader.

Comment: Thanks @nr_aus that's pretty much what I've been doing and I guess I'll have to continue doing.  I had hoped there would be a single-step option like on the writers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was mentioned by @nr_aus, you can try to [*import feature types*](https://desktopmanualbasic.safe.com/DesktopBasic4Components/4.08.ImportingReaderFeatureTypes.html) on the Reader menu for one of your geodatabases. It will present you with different feature classes in the geodatabase. Just select the ones that you have in your other readers, connect them up, and delete the old ones.

For a cleaner approach, I use the [**FeatureReader**](https://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/featurereader.htm) and [**FeatureWriter**](https://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/featurewriter.htm) transformers. You get more flexibility, in my opinion. You can initiate a FeatureReader with a [**Creator**](https://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/creator.htm) transformer.

Comment: Thanks @Fezter - the import feature types and then connect new/delete old suggestion is similar to what I've already been doing, I was hoping there was a single-step option similar to re-mapping the writers, but I guess not.  I had a look at the FeatureReader etc. and would use in my own workbenches, I will probably need to steer clear in these files since they're not mine and I don't want to change them too much, just giving them a tidy up